# is it possible to convert .nmf audio file to .wav format

Tags: wav, audio-conversion, nice-media-player

Can audio files in "nmf" format be converted to "wav" format? If so, what is the appropriate tool to do so?

If it cannot be converted, then what is the workaround?

Some sites on the net say that nmf files cannot be converted to other formats. Some claim that they have tools to convert.

Our client has audio files in nmf format. We would get access to them only when we go to their site physically. But before we get there, we want to be sure that we can convert their nmf files to wav files as our software expects only files in wav format.

It would be helpful if we can get some sample nmf files from somewhere or if we can generate nmf audio files ourselves so that we can test the conversion tool before we go the client site.

Any suggestion most welcome.

Comment: By NMF, you mean NICE Media Player? As from http://nmf.fileextensionguide.com/  "NICE Media Player audio file
The NMF file extension is associated with NICE Media Player and used for audio files in NICE Media file format.
Programs 
that open nmf files: NICE Media Player (Microsoft Windows)"

Comment: Have you been in touch with [NICE Support Services](http://www.nice.com/support-and-maintenance) ?

Comment: How about simply recording the audio playing back on your computer? You can use [follow this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/) and see if that works.

Comment: Post some non-secret example of this file here or on filesharing service like sendspace.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you're dealing with the sort of data produced by the NICE Audio and Call Recording software (http://www.nice.com/audio/call-recording-loggers). From that page:

NICE Recording highlights:
...
Highest Security Levels enabled by: AES Rijndael 256-bit encryption; MD5 fingerprinting; strict user access profiles; strong passwords policies; maker/Checker profiles; OS hardening policy
...

Note that encryption is likely to be present, so that's presumably what will be part of the outer container format.

There is a supposedly a player for it, so you should be able to record its output (assuming it doesn't offer an export function). You'll want a Windows version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443621/mac-os-x-virtual-audio-driver, I guess, or of Soundflower. that would allow you to capture the decoded waveform, and then capture that is a PCM file of such, and then compress it as per your preference. Its recorded voice, so your loss budget is (probably) going to be fine with the lossiness.

Comment: I've built a solution similar to the one you suggest, using Nice Media Player and CSCore to capture the audio, but it is limited to realtime conversion of a single stream.  I'd be very interested in a direct way to transcode the audio as per the question, or even some samples.

Comment: Get a trial version of the recorder?

Comment: I was told there is no trial version available.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do that, but it's very difficult. You have to usea nicelog recorder which should, if possible, be at the same version like the version of the recorded tapes. Without that it's nearly impossible.

Because the tapes require NICE codes which are delivered by a NICE player-application so that they can get converted back to "normal" audio.

So it is theoretically possible, but you have to put a lot of effort in it.